# If-statement, using maketitle and titlepage

Tags: environments, titles, conditionals

I've created a new environment using the NewEnviron-package, looking like

```
\NewEnviron{AbstractTitle}{
    \twocolumn[
    % \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}\noindent
        \BODY
    \end{onecolabstract}\vspace{.5cm}
    ]
}
```

and i would like a conditional that tests whether i have used \begin{titlepage} before calling my AbstractTitle-environment, so i don't have to change it whenever i want to change between titlepage and maketitle. 
(I haven't looked too far into the if-statements for TeX, so i might be a bit ignorant here..)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside, draft]{article}

\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{AbstractTitle}{
    \twocolumn[
    % \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}\noindent
        \BODY
    \end{onecolabstract}\vspace{.5cm}
    ]
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            \Huge
            \textbf{Machine Learning}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            and stuff
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    \begin{AbstractTitle}
        Abstract 
    \end{AbstractTitle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\if@titlepage`, although that simply tells whether or not titlepage was specified.  You can also check if \@currenv is "titlepage".

Comment: Why do you want to automate this?

Comment: Preferably so my classmates can use my template. They don't use LaTeX that much, so it would be good with a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `etoolbox` package you can modify the `titlepage` environment to set a toggle (boolean flag) when the environment is used. In the new abstract environment you can check for this toggle and call `\maketitle` only if the toggle is false.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside, draft]{article}

\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{My title}

\newtoggle{tpage} % note: toggles are false by default
\AtBeginEnvironment{titlepage}{\global\toggletrue{tpage}}

\NewEnviron{AbstractTitle}{
    \twocolumn[
    \iftoggle{tpage}{}{\maketitle}
    \begin{onecolabstract}\noindent
        \BODY
    \end{onecolabstract}\vspace{.5cm}
    ]
}

\begin{document}
    %\begin{titlepage}
    %    \begin{center}
    %        \vspace*{1cm}
    %        \Huge
    %        \textbf{Machine Learning}
    %        \vspace{0.5cm}
    %        \LARGE
    %        and stuff
    %    \end{center}
    %\end{titlepage}

    \begin{AbstractTitle}
        My abstract 
    \end{AbstractTitle}
\end{document}
```

Result (without `titlepage`):

[image]

With title page:

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm - thank you very much!